# Como puedo crear un Slider que expanda el contenedor como OverFlow?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Como puedo crear un Slider similar al que esta sombreado con rojo en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

requiero expandir el contenedor segun necesidad del cliente, pero que quede con la linea centrada tal como aparece en la imagen anterior, lo intente con overflow pero no toma los mismos estilos, y no encuentro mas clases o estilos que me ayuden con esta implementacion  html5, css o bootstrap

Estos son los estilos que actualmente estoy utilizando para que el contenedor se expanda

```css
.redimensionar {
   overflow: auto;
   resize: horizontal;
}
```

Este es el codigo adonde estoy llamando la clase "redimensionar"

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 redimensionar" id="izquierda">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col mt-5">
        <label class="text-secondary" for="espina-select">Espina</label>
        <select class="form-select" id="espina-select">
          <option selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
          <option value="1">Espina 1</option>
          <option value="2">Espina 2</option>
          <option value="3">Espina 3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 mt-5">
        <label class="text-secondary">Lado</label>
        <div class="form-group mt-5">
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline mr-4 align-items-center">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="lado" value="izquierdo">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="izquierdo">
              izquierdo
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline mr-4">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="lado" value="derecho">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="derecho">
              derecho
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-9 mt-5">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="text-secondary" for="causa">Causa</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="causa">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 mt-5">
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary mt-5">Agregar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 mt-5">
      <table class="table table-row-bordered border-4">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Espina</th>
            <th>Causa</th>
            <th>Lado</th>
            <th>Orden</th>
            <th>Es causa raiz</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <td>{{item.espina}}</td>
            <td>{{item.causa}}</td>
            <td>{{item.lado}}</td>
            <td>{{item.orden}}</td>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.isChecked"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-center" id="derecha">
    <p>Aqui va el gráfico del pescado</p>
  </div>
</div>
```